# How can I manually assign individual vertex UV coordinates?

Tags: uv

I've been learning a great deal about the various sophisticated ways to assign UV coordinates in blender, including unwrapping, seams, etc.

However, sometimes for simple tests it would just be so much faster if I could just write the UV coordinates for each vertex manually. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Not, not directly through from the 3DView at least, as far as I know. You can manually edit the UV coordinates of each individual vertex manually in the UV Image Editor through, and you could probably also do this from the Python API too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the uv manually in the [UV/Image Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/editors/uv/index.html).

**After** marking seams and unwrapping, open up the UV Editor.
[image: uv editor]

If you check **Normalized**, you can select vertices and input their coordinates in the range of 0 - 1.
[image: uv editor normalized UV Vertex]

When you check the *Keep UV and edit mode selection in sync* button [image: Keep UV and edit mode selection in sync], the 3D View selection is the same as the UV editor selection.

You could select vertices in the 3D View and input their uv coordinates in the UV editor.
[image: uv editing]

Note, that you can also use the standard select, grab, rotate and scale tools in the 2D space of the UV editor.

Comment: The link in your answer no longer works. An updated link is somewhere around here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/editors/uv/index.html